# Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 14

Tags: java, android

So i recently switched the target of my android project to 4.0. Now i have practically errors on every line and the error "Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 14" on the console. So my question is, how do i change this to work with api 14 and compile? thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**If you're supporting API levels < 19 (4.4)**

In eclipse:
Right click your project -> properties -> from the side bar, pick "Java Compiler" and then change Compiler compliance level to 1.6

**If you're support API levels >= 19**

You shouldn't see this issue. If you do, make sure that your project's `minSdkVersion` is properly configured.

Comment: Thank you. But i still have many many errors that say "variable cannot be resolved"

Comment: Clean your project by clicking on Project -> Clean, see if this helps. If it doesn't, please post some code or try to restart eclipse

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with @Eran, this error cause by setting `Project build target` to 4.0 (API 14). If change to Java 1.6, you'll can't use Java 1.7 sode style, for ex: `ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();`.

 To fix this, set your target to 4.4 (API 19) or higher.

Comment: This problem will only arise if your project isn't targeting 4.4 and higher. Most people do not target 4.4 and higher but lower versions like 4.0, to support more devices. So your solution won't really work for them. Moreover, if you use Android Studio you can use Java 1.7 code style even when you support API 14.

Comment: @Eran How this possible in Android Studio. When i use Strings in switch case how its works in Android Studio.

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim please clarify.

Comment: @Eran if you use Android Studio you can use Java 1.7 code style even when you support API 14. In this statement how the apk generated if my minsdk as 14 and i use the switch case with string object then.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps solved error in my Eclipse project

1. Go to android project
2. right click on the project
3. select properties
4. There is a option named 'Android' in right side menu
5. Select higher level API then API 14 or any other API that's installed in you SDK manager

and you're done.